# Cross-validation and LASSO plot

Tags: cross-validation, lasso, lars

I am not sure about some parts of the following plots:

-- I do not understand what does the expression on x-axis means (first figure) and how to interpret that.

-- What is the bars and the points in figure 2 and 3 refer to.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what software and commands you used to create the plots.

Comment: I used "lars" function that available in R program, I just would like to understand it generally. what do they mean ?

Comment: Because I'm sure you read the documentation before posting this question, what part of the lars documentation is unclear to you?

Comment: @ General Abrial, Of course, but  I don,t know about the expression on x-axis (figure 1)

Comment: The `lars` function isn't in base R, so it must be in some package, but you haven't specified one. Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with. Then this will be answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The x-axis is the size of the coefficient relative to the $L_1$ norm of the coefficient vector.... probably. I'm assuming that you created that plot with the default plot commands in `lars` and this is what the documentation describes.
2. The bars in figures 2 and 3 represent an estimate of the sampling error around the mean estimate of MSE. I don't know how you generated them, so I don't know how wide the interval is. Default values are described in the documentation. The red points in figure 3 are the mean estimates of the MSE. The colored vertical lines are the locations of the minimum MSE and minimum MSE plus 1 standard error (by default).

Comment: 1- so, is this expression related to the value of the penalty term $\lambda$ ,and what is max $\beta$ here. 2-  some people said the red point is MSE for resulting model and other said is cross-validation curve. are they equivalent to the mean estimates , also mean estimates of what?  Thanks

Comment: @Ereck 1. yes 2. They said the red point was MSE because it is. Look at the label for the Y axis of the plot. Then consider what the meaning of the initials "MSE."

Comment: @ General Abrial, I know MSE= mean square error. 1- in which sense they are related.

Comment: are the points in figure 2 also refer to  the mean estimates of the MSE?

Comment: as far as I can tell